# Java how to take user input

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

Can anyone please tell me what is wrong with my code, i was just trying to add scanner in java and it was showing me an error on package line

```
import java.util.Scanner;

package scaner;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
   System.out.println("enter your number");
   int number;
   number = in.nextInt();
   System.out.println("your number is" + " " + number);
}
```

}

Comment: [*...and it was showing me an error on package line*](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/17-errors) But package statements come *before* imports

Comment: Also, there's no class declaration here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the **main** method must be inside a class.
Also, delete the "*package scaner;*" line.
If you want, you can also simplify the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class className{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
        int number = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Your number is: " + number);
    }
}
```

Comment: Good! But let's also stick to naming convention, while we're at it. The class should be called `ClassName`, with a capiital "C".